# can't run jsp with css from tomcat

Tags: java, css, jsp, tomcat

i have problem running my project from Tomcat. 
i used IDE before and never faced this problem till now. 
i have my jsp with a link to css, that looks like this:

```
<%@page import="data.PageData"%>
<%@page import="dao.pageDao"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="pagedata" class="data.PageData" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title><jsp:getProperty name="pagedata" property="title" /></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="big_wrapper">
    <header id=top_header>
      <h1>Site Header</h1>
    </header>
 <div id="new_div">
  <section id="main_section">
  <jsp:getProperty property="maintext" name="pagedata"/> 

  </section>
  <aside id="side_menu">
    <%= request.getAttribute("pagemenu") %>
  </aside>
  </div>
  <footer id="the_footer">
    Copyright  2012 &copy;
  </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>;
```

i put it in my tomcat's project root directory, just where i have my jsp. but whenever i try to run it, it shows my jsp page, but with no styles (it doesn't see main.css). 
what should i do to display it with styles? 
p.s. should i put smth in web.xml?

Answer (score 2):

What is URL mapping? Your main.css is specified without path so it's is relative to the path in your URL mapping and that is where you should put main.css file.

To test if you are able to access main.css or not, in Firefox, you view the html source code and click on the main.css. Firefox will lead you to the source of main.css. If you are unable to see you expecting css code, then your path is wrong. you might want to do something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/my/url/mapping/path/main.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../my/relative/path/main.css">
```

If it works before when you run it with IDE, it might be that your IDE start your webapp without context path and when you run it under tomcat it is with context path. You need to make sure that the css or other resource are of correct path.

Comment: The URL used for main.css will be relative to the URL used to load main.jsp. This should work, unless the OP has some weird backend-forwarding set up.

Comment: If main.jsp is accessed directly, then the main.css should also be accessible. in many cases, like spring mvc or java ee, this is likely not the case.

Comment: It would be good to see the URL being used to access the JSP ;)

Comment: it displays error when i try to load main.css from page source in Firefox. and i tried both variants in my css of the link tag that you posted, none of them work. or maybe i should change smth else, not just the link in jsp for css?

Comment: Christopher, i actually run servlet, that redirects to my jsp with help of `getRequestDispatcher`. i mapped it in my web.xml file under url: `http://localhost:8080/engine/SiteController/`

Comment: then your stylesheet url should be `/engine/main.css`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guy for disturbing you, i found the mistake, it was in xml mapping, i shouldn't have put "/" in the very end of url-pattern